# Approximate sin x by a sum of series in java

Tags: java

sin⁡(x)=x-x^3/3!+x^5/5!-x^7/7!+x^9/9!-x^11/11!…+x^25/25!-x^27/27!,-3.1416<x<3.1416

I need to display the following:

```
Enter x (in radians): 2
Term 1 = 2.0
Term 2 = -1.3333333333333333
Term 3 = 0.26666666666666666
Term 4 = -0.025396825396825393
Term 5 = 0.0014109347442680773
Term 6 = -5.130671797338463E-5
Term 7 = 1.3155568711124264E-6
Term 8 = -2.5058226116427168E-8
Term 9 = 3.6850332524157597E-10
Term 10 = -4.309980412182175E-12
Term 11 = 4.1047432496973094E-14
Term 12 = -3.2448563238713907E-16
Term 13 = 2.163237549247594E-18
Term 14 = -1.2326139881752673E-20
Sin(2.0)=0.9092974268256817
```

My code:

```
   import java.util.Scanner;
 public class SinX {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        double ans,Term1;
        System.out.print("Enter x (in radians):"); 
        double inputvalue= input.nextDouble();
        ans=inputvalue;       
        if ( (ans<-3.1416)||(ans>3.1416) ) {
         System.out.println("Value invalid!");
        } else {
             System.out.println("Term1="+ ans);
             int plusMinus=1;
             int printedTerm=2;
             double factorial =0;
             
             for(int oraginalNum=3;oraginalNum<=27;oraginalNum +=2){
                if(plusMinus <0 ) {
                for (double factorialcount=1; factorialcount <= oraginalNum ; factorialcount++)
                {
            
            factorial*=factorialcount;
             }
            ans=ans-( (Math.pow(ans,oraginalNum) )
            /( factorial) );
             System.out.println ("Term "+printedTerm+"="+ ans);
             printedTerm ++;
             plusMinus +=2;
        }else{
            for (double factorialcount=1; factorialcount <= oraginalNum ; factorialcount++)
            {
            factorial*=factorialcount;
            }
            ans= ans+ ( (Math.pow(ans,oraginalNum) )
            /( factorial) );
            System.out.println ("Term "+printedTerm+"="+ ans);
            printedTerm ++;
            plusMinus -=2;
        }
    } 
      System.out.println("sin("+inputvalue+")"+"="+ans);

}
  }      
}
```

I try to test ,but the output  cannot display.
I do not know how to fix. Can you tell me how to change my code?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7nDyh.png)

I hope I can display the output.

Comment: Fix the indentation of your source code, so you can see where which block starts and ends.

Comment: It _seems_ (if the indentation doesn't fool me) that you have a sequence of `if() {... } else { ...} else { ... }` which isn't legal code. Did you maybe mean `if() { ...} else if() {...} else {...}`?

Comment: And this `if(plusMinus<0) {` no code in the block at all, it's just empty braces.  You might want to fix the indentation (some people can read code without proper indentation but it's certainly more difficult) and then check the code logic carefully, you seem to have missed a few things.

Comment: And this `for(int baseNum=3;baseNum<=27;baseNum+=2) { if(plusMinus<0) {` again is just an empty block after the `if`, I don't think you've attempted to solve this problem the way your instructor wants you to.  Maybe just concentrate on the parts you are having trouble with instead of adding that extraneous block of if-else statements.

Comment: The solution to this is _definitely_ to indent your code correctly until you notice mismatched braces.  @Progman isn't just saying this to make it easier for us, it's to solve your problem.